# Is AVHRR 5.3 SST data correct in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, units

I am curious about how to scale the units of the AVHRR 5.3 Sea Surface Temperature data. The original units of this dataset is K, but it also has a scale factor of 0.001 (I'm not sure for what). The units seem to be wrong because they are not reasonable when converting to Celsius, it should be >25°C (or 298 °K) in the Tropics). Am I doing something wrong here?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/CDR/SST_PATHFINDER/V53')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2014-05-01', '2014-06-14'))

var seaSurfaceTemperature = dataset.select('sea_surface_temperature')
var rescale = function(image) {
  var img = image.multiply(0.001)
  return img.copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
}

var sst = seaSurfaceTemperature.map(rescale)
var visParams = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 28,
  palette: [
    '030d81', '0519ff', '05e8ff', '11ff01', 'fbff01', 'ff9901', 'ff0000',
    'ad0000'
  ],
}
Map.setCenter(-121.99, -2.11, 2)
Map.addLayer(sst.mean(), visParams, 'Sea Surface Temperature')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2d590a96c4dbf4aeda156bdfe30f26e3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [EE dataset catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_CDR_SST_PATHFINDER_V53) says scale is `0.001` and offset is `273.15`. I'm guessing the scale is wrong here. If it was `0.01`, you'd get reasonable temperatures. This would give you the temperature in C (because of the offset):

```
var rescale = function(image) {
  var img = image.multiply(0.01)
  return img.copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ae8ab159821aab73e40bfda1413c052b

Comment: You get Kelvin if you apply the (correct) scale and the offset. If you apply the scale but not the offset, you get Celcius.

Comment: Thank you...It was tricky, the GEE team should correct this mistake...

Comment: I've submitted a bug report. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156871108

Comment: It has been corrected: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_CDR_SST_PATHFINDER_V53. @LuisLizcano, since this was a platform bug that is now resolved, would you please consider removing this post, as it is no longer an open issue relevant to others.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to delete it. If someone else can, please do it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this issue up @LuisLizcano and for being amenable to it being removed. I've requested a moderator take a look.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention @JustinBraaten. My initial thought is that this Q&A is relevant information and it would be a disservice to the community to delete it. I would recommend adding an answer indicating that the bug has been resolved including appropriate references.

Comment: Sounds good - done.

Answer (score 2):

**Documentation issue resolved**

The `sea_surface_temperature` scaling factor listed in the dataset's [band description](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_CDR_SST_PATHFINDER_V53#bands) has been corrected from `0.001` to `0.01`.

Note that scale and offset values can also be fetched from image metadata:

```js
var img = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/CDR/SST_PATHFINDER/V53').first();
var scale = ee.Number(img.get('sea_surface_temperature_scale'));
var offset = ee.Number(img.get('sea_surface_temperature_offset'));
```